# Check the value of multiple element with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 7 dropdown with the class name="dd". and i have 7 textbox with the class name ="tt". each text box corresponds to each dropdown.
now, i have to check

```
if(dropdown value is equal to 1)
    text box can not be empty.
```

so to do this what i am doing:

```
function checkOpenHours() {
        if ($('.dd').val() == 1 && $('.tt').val() == "") {

                alert("Please select an opening hour.");
                return false;

        }
    }
```

and i am calling this function like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Update hour" Height="35px" 
        onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return checkOpenHours()"/>
```

BUT The problem is, this only works for the first dropdown and textbox.
It does not work for the other 6 dropdown and textbox ..!!

what am i doing wrong?? any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.val()` method returns the value from the first element in the jQuery object.

You could do this instead:

```
function checkOpenHours() {
    var $dd = $('.dd'),
        $tt = $('.tt'),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < $dd.length; i++) {
        if ($dd.eq(i).val() == 1 && $tt.eq(i).val() == "") {
            alert("Please select an opening hour.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing there is first putting the result of `$('.dd')` and `$('.tt')` into variables, because although using `$('.dd')` and `$('.tt')` in the loop would work it would be inefficient because it would recreate them (complete with DOM access) on every iteration. Then I'm using the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the elements at the current `i` index.

I'm using a standard `for` rather than a jQuery `.each()` because it makes it easy to return from the outer function.

Comment: hi..thanks..sorry about the last comment. I have deleted that. The problem is, even though I enter text in the textbox, it keeps showing the alert..!! do you have any clue??

Comment: Seems to work fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/M9YP8/ - If you're having further problems you'll need to show more of your code, perhaps in a fiddle of your own...

Answer (score 1):

`val()` only returns the value of the first element in a jQuery collection.

You should probably use `.each()` for this.

Something like

```
var allOkay = true;
$('.dd').each(function(id, item) {
    var $dropDown = $(item);
    var $textbox = $dropDown.siblings('.tt') // You'll need to change this according to your HTML!

    if ($dropDown.val() == 1 && $textbox.val() == '') {
        allOkay = false;
    }
});
if (!allOkay) {
    alert("Ze opening hourz! You did not enter zem!")
}
```